# Autogenerating classes for XSD containing an element which is a C# keyword

Tags: c#, xsd, deserialization, xsd.exe

I'm using XSD.exe to generate classes from XSD -> C#, with auto-serialization.

One element of the XSD is called `event` and because this is a C# keyword, the generated classname is `@event`. I never knew this was even a valid class name but it's ugly.

I know I can't control XSD.exe's choice of classnames - they map to the XSD element names. *BUT* Is there a way I can manually rename my `@event` class and C#/.NET will still know how to do the serialization? Is there some attribute I can add to the class definition for instance?

Obviously I will have to redo this each time I regenerate the classes.

Answer (score 0):

You can decorate classes with attributes that control serialization.

See this MSDN Article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2baksw0z(v=vs.110).aspx

The MSDN article has this to say about class names:

> There are two attributes that can be applied to a class (and only a
>   class): XmlRootAttribute and XmlTypeAttribute. These attributes are
>   very similar. The XmlRootAttribute can be applied to only one class:
>   the class that, when serialized, represents the XML document's opening
>   and closing element—in other words, the root element. The
>   XmlTypeAttribute, on the other hand, can be applied to any class,
>   including the root class.

```
[XmlRoot("NewGroupName")]
[XmlType("NewTypeName")]
public class Group{
    public Employee[] Employees;
}
```

> If this class is compiled, and the XML Schema Definition tool is used
>   to generate its schema, you would find the following XML describing
>   Group.

```
<xs:element name="NewGroupName" type="NewTypeName">
```

> In contrast, if you were to serialize an instance of the class, only
>   NewGroupName would be found in the XML document.

```
<NewGroupName>
    . . .
</NewGroupName>
```

Comment: Generally link-only answers are frowned upon (in case the link becomes broken). Could you provide a small example?

Comment: I've updated with examples from the linked MSDN page that relate to the question